# Unit testing function which calls external async API

Tags: actionscript-3, unit-testing, asynchronous, tdd

I really want to grasp TDD approach and integrate it into my coding behaviors, but I have really hard time to understand how do people test some complicated cases. For example, consider this situation: I have a game, consisting of levels. When the user passes the level, I should display a dialog, informing him of his current position amongst his friends. The dialog can show only 3 places, amongst which the current user should have the highest place and score. If the user has less than 2 friends, I must display "fake" friends in this dialog.

So, I have a function, which receives a vector of objects, containing UIDs of users (by which they are represented in some social network) and their scores and places in the leaderboard for the given level. The function should be called after the game level ends and it should marshal those users in right order in the dialog (view) which displays the users in proper order, according to their place, scores etc. So this function looks like this in pseudocode:

```
public function marshallUsers(users:Vector.<User>):void {
  // Add necessary fake users, if the vector length less than 3

  // Compute social network request for users's photos
  // basically it just a string with comma-separated user ids

  // Enquiry social network API asynchronously, calling callback
  // function when the request succeeds. This is singleton.
}

private function callback(users:Array):void
{
    // fill the user portraits in the dialog
}
```

So how can I extract what exactly should I test in the marshallUsers function? Inner object state changes? How can I test the function which not only relies on external global object, but also logically continues after the asynchronous call succeeds? How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 1):

If your case is "too complicated" that is often because it is too broad.

From your description, `marshallUsers` doesn't really seem to perform much logic internally (except perhaps adding fake friends?). It just calls a sequence of other objects? If so then there isn't much to test. You should be testing the individual components that `marshallUsers` calls upon in their own tests.

What you could be testing is whether `marshallUsers` correctly handles various output states from each of the components it uses (such as a valid set of users, less than 3 users, unable to get a response etc). You would mock the various components to provide these dummy responses.

Remember, you are ideally only testing the logic within `marshallUsers`, everything else should be isolated from it.

For what it's worth, in the tests we do for similar cases to yours, we do them firstly as I have described, but then normally also have at least one "end-to-end" test which calls an API just to make sure it all fits together correctly. The argument is of course that with well thought out tests you shouldn't need to - but the real world is not always well thought out.

Comment: thank you for the thorough answer! So, basically if I got your response right, I should test sub-components of the marshallUsers function, right? What if some of them are private? I thought that TDD employes the testing of public interfaces, to make sure they give correct results in the corner cases, right? My function not only adds fake users, it marshalls them in the right order to pass them to view component later on. Social API adds complexity here, because I shouldn't be enquiring fake friends and both functions take care about it by utilizing private members. I'm so confused =(